# Converting answer to comment on migrated post

Tags: support, answers, comments

I am trying to convert [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14940/is-the-content-of-a-wordpress-blog-gpl/14942#14942) into comment on original post, but get:

> Failed to process action, target post id may be invalid.

Likely has something to do with question being migrated from elsewhere?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this function can only be used -- for now -- on posts that have an *owner*.